# MapView become nil during the runtime

Tags: swift

I am new to Xcode, I create a mapView Controller to display my map, and in the didLoadView function, it seems good when compiling, however, when I run the app, the error shows up, Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.  it says the mapView has nil value

```
import MapKit

final class MapViewController: UIViewController{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Set initial location in ANU
      let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)
      mapView.centerToLocation(initialLocation)
      
      let oahuCenter = CLLocation(latitude: 21.4765, longitude: -157.9647)
      let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: oahuCenter.coordinate,
        latitudinalMeters: 50000,
        longitudinalMeters: 60000)
      mapView.setCameraBoundary(
        MKMapView.CameraBoundary(coordinateRegion: region),
        animated: true)
      
      let zoomRange = MKMapView.CameraZoomRange(maxCenterCoordinateDistance: 200000)
      mapView.setCameraZoomRange(zoomRange, animated: true)
      
      mapView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you connect your `@IBOutlet weak var mapView` to the MapView on the `MapViewController.storyboard`? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: You haven’t created the MapView that your variable represents. All you’ve done is say the mapView variable will definitely (you use a !) be a MapView when the variable is first accessed. It isn’t so it crashes.

Comment: Also I notice that you haven't added the protocol for the delegate methods. I suggest you take a look at this tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/16/1/setting-up, it should clear up some of the issues for you

Comment: it seems that the app could not load the main storyboard correctly. When I create a new single view project, there is no init Main.storyboard at the beginning, then i create a main storyboard manually and to set up in the info.plist, however, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import MapKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView! 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     let initialLocation = MKPointAnnotation()
            initialLocation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)
            initialLocation.title = "location"
            mapView.addAnnotation(initialLocation)
            
                  let oahuCenter = CLLocation(latitude: 21.4765, longitude: -157.9647)
                  let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                    center: oahuCenter.coordinate,
                    latitudinalMeters: 50000,
                    longitudinalMeters: 60000)
                  mapView.setCameraBoundary(
                    MKMapView.CameraBoundary(coordinateRegion: region),
                    animated: true)
                  
                  let zoomRange = MKMapView.CameraZoomRange(maxCenterCoordinateDistance: 200000)
                  mapView.setCameraZoomRange(zoomRange, animated: true)
                  mapView.delegate = self
      }
}
```

Comment: You don't even have a class name.  How does that help Wenxi Wu?